# Aliasing python variables without dict

Tags: python, reference

I'm just implementing a class that requires an attribute to store a reference of another attribute as a cursor. See the following:

```
class foo:
    def __init__(self):
        self.egg=[4,3,2,1,[4,3,2,1]]
        self.spam=#some reference or pointer analog represent self.egg[4][2], for example

    def process(self):
        # do something on self.egg[self.spam]
        pass
```

I don't want a `dict` because self.spam should only represent one item, and using a `dict` I would have to consume indefinite unnecessary memory. Is there some pythonic way to implement `self.spam` above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could store the indices in `self.spam`, and use a property to access the value from `self.egg` given the current value of `self.spam`:

```
class Foo(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.egg = [4,3,2,1,[4,3,2,1]]
        self.spam = (4,2)

    def process(self):
        # do something on self.egg[self.spam]
        print(self.eggspam)
        pass

    @property
    def eggspam(self):
        result = self.egg
        for item in self.spam:
            result = result[item]
        return result

f = Foo()
f.process()
# 2

f.spam = (1,)
f.process()
# 3
```